# Calculating $S$-matrix in string theory

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral, s-matrix-theory, ghosts

To calculate string $S$-matrix, we mainly use Faddeev-Popov gauge  fixing  method, as in chapter 6 of Polchinsky's book  《string theory》.  But  in section 6.2, 'tree level amplitude', I didn't  find  that  it  calculates  the  path integral corresponding to the ghost  fields, it only  calculates the generating  functional  corresponding  to  the  matter  fields, so  i still  don't  know  how to calculate  the  string  path  integral to compute tree level amplitude. Can any one elaborate that?

The following is  from .section 6.2 in Polchinsky 《String  theory》:
[image]
if you have  the  book in your hand you can look at it.
I think that generating  functional  is only for  ordinary  field  but  does not deal  with  ghost  field. in the next section 6.3 it starts dealing with calculating particular vertex operator expectation value using this generating  functional and never compute  ghost fields.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you want? The standard expression I know for the stringy S-matrix is a gauge-fixed version that *does* integrate over the ghost fields. Perhaps writing down the expressions (and an explanation of the notation used) would make it clearer what the issue here is.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last sentence (v3)? The next section 6.3 is precisely devoted to the $bc$ ghost system.

Answer (score 1):

Your doubt is actually a symptom that you need to go back to the chapter 5. Ghosts insertions are related to moduli (b-ghosts) and fixing vertex operators (c-ghosts). In chapter 5, section 5.3, in the Riemann-Roch theorem proof, he shows that in order to conserve the ghost number the number of b-ghost insertions minus the number of c-ghost insertions should be $-3/2\chi$, where $\chi$ is the Euler number of the manifold. Then the equation 5.3.18 gives the value of the Faddev-Popov measure for those insertions, the ghost part of the path integral. In chapter 6, section 6.3, he work out all this explicitly for the $S_2$ for arbitrary numbers of bc-ghost obeying total ghost number $3/2\chi$.

The example given in section 6.3
$$
\langle c(z_1)c(z_2)c(z_3)\tilde{c}(z_4)\tilde{c}(z_5)\tilde{c}(z_6)\rangle_{S_2}=C_{S_2}^{g}\left\| \matrix{1&1&1 \\z_1&z_2&z_3\\z_1^{2}&z^{2}_{2}&z^{2}_{3}}\right\|\left\| \matrix{1&1&1 \\\tilde{z}_4&\tilde{z}_5&\tilde{z}_6\\\tilde{z}_4^{2}&\tilde{z}^{2}_{5}&\tilde{z}^{2}_{6}}\right\|\implies$$ $$\implies\langle c(z_1)c(z_2)c(z_3)\tilde{c}(z_4)\tilde{c}(z_5)\tilde{c}(z_6)\rangle_{S_2}=\pm C_{S_2}^{g}z_{12}z_{23}z_{13}\tilde{z}_{45}\tilde{z}_{46}\tilde{z}_{56}
$$
where the determinants comes from the determinant $\det(\mathcal{C}_{0j}^{a}(\sigma_i))$ of the equation 5.3.18.

Latter in the chapter 6 we see that this ghost insertions are necessary in order to the amplitudes be independent of the positions of the unintegrated vertex operators. They are there to cancel the denominators $(z_{12}z_{23}z_{13}\tilde{z}_{45}\tilde{z}_{46}\tilde{z}_{56})^{-1}$ produced by the unintegrated vertex operators.

Comment: Reading this I start to see ghosts.